# Why can't I add this int by 1?

Tags: android, int, addition

This is a bit frustrating, because I don't know why it's not adding. I have a public integer (public int intVar;), and a method that I want to increase by 1. I've tried intVar++, intVar+=1 and intVar = intVar + 1;...

So why can't I increase this integer by 1?

```
public class activityMain extends Activity {
    public int intVar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cdtracks);
        intVar = 1;
    }

    public void myMethod() {
        intVar = intVar+1;
        Log.d("MYTAG", "intVar="+intVar)
        //everytime I call the method, it will always say 1. 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is intVar affected in any other code? Can you show an instance where myMethod() is actually called?

Comment: It seems OK (except of the missing `;` in last line) so I'm gonna go with "are you sure this is the actual code? maybe there's something you don't show us because you didn't think it's important?"

Comment: @Maximus well my activity is quite long... but the myMethod() is called when pressing a button. I have logcats everywhere so I know it's calling the method just fine and the application works, just it doesn't add that integer.

@MByD This isn't the actual code, cause like I replied to Maximus, it's super long. I have a Logcat reporting back to me the intVar and it always says 1, never 2, 3 ,4...

Comment: make sure you didn't declare `intVar` in `myMethod` as well. Also, is it called on the same instance of the activity, or it is called in different times?

Comment: @MByd, it isn't declared in the myMethod, only in onCreate. Maybe I'm misunderstanding you...when you say declare... did you mean like public int intVal? If that's the case, it is declared outside of the methods.

Answer (score 2):

Did you make sure the onCreate that you show is actually executed? What happens if you call your method twice?

Comment: The onCreate is executed. I even initialized the integer in the method instead. HOwever I will try running the method twice, that's a good idea...

Comment: This worked...I threw the math into its own method and just ran the formula twice in the method...it worked. Why would it work when running twice?

Comment: @Anthony Honciano: Where are you calling MyMethod(). If it is in the constructor then it will be called before onCreate() and therefore intVar will be zero before the first time you increment it thus meaning that the result of the first MyMethod call will be '1' and thus the result you are seeing. Try saying "public int intVar = 1;" and I bet you will get the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

Add a log statement to the OnCreate method, if you have not already done so. That might tell you something. You will probably find that the intVar variable should be stored in the savedInstanceState bundle, to make it persistent. That is done in the onSaveInstanceState method of the activity.